# Linear Regression over clusters

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression, k-means

I have 10 k means Clusters from a data set. I want to build linear regression model with all these clusters separately. 
ie. I want 10 linear regression models. How can i do this using loops in R

Comment: With a loop. (Serious: what have you tried?)

Comment: `lapply(split(train, cluster), lm, formula = price ~.)`   Please review [mcve].

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
This is what i really wanted.
This code is basically from Hadley Wikham's github post "Managing multiple models"

```
house.cluster <- kmeans(scale(house), 10, 50)
house$cluster <- house.cluster$cluster

by_cluster <- train %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  nest()


cluster_model <- function(df) {
  lm(price ~., data = df)
}

models <- by_cluster %>%
  mutate(
    model  = data %>% map(cluster_model)
  )


models <- models %>%
  mutate(
    glance  = model %>% map(broom::glance),
    rsq     = glance %>% map_dbl("r.squared")
  )
```

Now I want to predict my Test set with these 10 models.
How can this be done